# does pipe operator modify its input/output? Or is ls aware of pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, ls

consider the following... when I execute 'ls' without any flags, it returns the results in a single line, like the following:

```
me@myComp /cygdrive/c/test/
$ ls
folder1/  folder2/  folder3/
```

now, if I want to grep the results for something, say '2', I get the following:

```
me@myComp /cygdrive/c/test/
$ ls | grep 2
folder2/
```

Shouldn't it return the entire line? I would expect this result has I used `ls -l | grep 2`.

It seems to me that either the pipe operator is changing the input to grep in some way, or that somehow ls is aware of the pipe and changes its own output.

`folder1/  folder2/  folder3/` is a single string, is it not? so how then does grep know to only return `folder2/`, and not `folder1/ folder2/ folder3/`?

Comment: I've long wondered about that myself. It does appear that ls is aware that its output is going to a pipe, and so formats each result as a separate line. If output is to the terminal, it formats more compactly. I don't know if this is "official" behavior, or just a convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the manpage for `ls`, namely the flag `-1`:

> -1      (The numeric digit ``one''.)  Force output to be one entry per
>                line.  **This is the default when output is not to a terminal.**

If you want to force multi-column output use

> -C      Force multi-column output; this is the default when output is to
>                a terminal.

So to answer your question, yes, `ls` is *aware* where the output goes and it has well-defined behavior depending on it which you can easily override.

Comment: very interesting... I've since found this as well that explains [how ls is pipe aware](http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/). it seems it's using isatty to test the file descriptor and vary its output depending on what it's writing to -- which makes me wonder how it's working on cygwin :P

Comment: Presumably, the cygwin implementation of `ls` is different. The POSIX standard requires one file per line unless an option explicitly changes this, or if the output is to a terminal (in which case, the output is implementation-defined).